# Respond to individual mouse events before global ones

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am using an array of JLabels in which multiple objects are clickable (only one shown below for simplicity). When each is clicked, it should run a short bit of code that changes a switch based on which object is clicked. After that, it should run a universal bit of code that is run for each JLabel, but executed slightly differently based on the switch.

The problem is that the example below runs the "//run this code second" bit first, and then runs the "//run this code first" bit. Is there any way to reverse this behavior?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class ListenToMice extends JFrame implements MouseListener 
{
    private JLabel[] difference = new JLabel[11];
    public ListenToMice( ) 
    {
        difference[1].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    //run this code first
                }

            });
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //run this code second
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra ending curly braces `}`, and I'm not sure whether this code you used to compile and test the behavior, i just removed it pasted below
`difference[1].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    //run this code first
                    }
            
            });`

Comment: @KeshShan Sorry about that. I fixed it now. It is still lacking the gui component, but if a gui is added, the discribed behavior is displayed

Comment: oh, nevermind, i just solved my own problem. Posting answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set the event you want first as "mousePressed" and the second as "mouseReleased". This way the first event is called when the user presses down and the second is called as the user releases the button. Not sure weather this would work with a longer code that took the computer awhile to process, but for this short code, it works fine.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class ListenToMice extends JFrame implements MouseListener 
{
    private JLabel[] difference = new JLabel[11];
    public ListenToMice( ) 
    {
        difference[1].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    //this code will now run first (see how it is "mousePressed" above this text
                }

            });
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
//put code you want second here
    }
}
```